# Controlling multiple drones using ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using ROS Kinetic and I am trying to pilot multiple drones using ardrone_autonomy, I just learned how to use ardrone_autonomy to control a single drone. The way I did it is as follow:

1. Create a workspace .... `mkdir –p ~/catkin_ws/src cd ~/catkin_ws/src catkin_init_workspace` ….
2. Download dependencies …. `git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy cd .. rosdep install –from-paths src –ignore-src` ….
3. Build the workspace and compile the packages …. `catkin_make` ….
4. Source the environment …. `source devel/setup.bash` ….
5. Create a package called drone_application …. `cd ~/catkin_ws/src catkin_create_pkg drone_application srd_msgs rospy roscpp cv_bridge` ….
6. Create a launch file called `dronelaunch.launch` ….
7. Run `roscore`

Launch drone

```
launch.launch roslaunch dronelaunch.launch
```

I am not sure how the process would be different for multiple drones! Any help would be really appreciated.

*************************************************************************************************************************************Thank you very much! I really appreciated your answer. It seems very straightforward but my only problem is connecting the drones to the same PC. in your tutorial, you created the static IP address on your router. I cannot do that since I am using school's wifi and I do not have a permission to mess with the routers. Any suggestions on how to do that on my personal laptop?
You must be busy with your own stuff and I know that this might be taking some of your time, so I am really down for any tutoring sessions with you, of course if you are available.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295383/controlling-multiple-drones-using-ros/) by [melhazzouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/36090/melhazzouri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [melhazzouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/36090/melhazzouri/) on 2018-06-26**:
So the only difference would be the launch file?

**Comment by [melhazzouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/36090/melhazzouri/) on 2018-06-26**:
Also how would I connect my PC to the drones? Thank you !!!

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-07-03**:
Did you manage in the end? if I posted an answer with how you would connect the PC to the multiple drones, and more, if anything needs clarification please don't hesitate to ask

**Comment by [melhazzouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/36090/melhazzouri/) on 2018-07-03**:
No, I am actually still trying. My problem is the connection and I cannot seem to figure it out. Thank you man!

**Comment by [melhazzouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/36090/melhazzouri/) on 2018-07-06**:
Hi! I was wondering if you would be available for any paid tutoring sessions! Exchanging emails or even texts back and forth would be good for me if you have the time.

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-07-06**:
no need to pay, I'm also pretty new to all of this and am happy to help if there is something I know that can be of value. If you want to do it via email, that's good with me. You can email me at ohanoch@gmail.com and let me know what you tried so far and whats giving you problems.

**Comment by [sophvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40739/sophvk/) on 2022-03-31**:
Is there a maximum number of drones you can control? Do you know if ROS can handle a large number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used `ardrone_autonomy` in a while, but it is does have a [launch file](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/blob/02dc8eb7b276953077596fd844ce43881d8be524/launch/ardrone_group.launch) that shows you how to do this (this is a direct copy and paste):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- Example launch file for multiple AR Drones -->
<launch>
  <!-- Include the ardrone launch file for each drone.
       IMPORTANT: Ensure the namespace for each include is unique. -->

  <group ns="ardrone1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="ardrone1" />
    <include file="$(find ardrone_autonomy)/launch/ardrone.launch">
      <arg name="ip" value="192.168.1.152" />
      <!-- Choose ultrasound frequencies to help reduce interference between drones.
           Available values are '7' or '8'. -->
      <arg name="freq" value="7" />
    </include>
  </group>

  <!-- Add second drone -->
  <group ns="ardrone2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="ardrone2" />
    <include file="$(find ardrone_autonomy)/launch/ardrone.launch">
      <arg name="ip" value="192.168.1.157" />
      <arg name="freq" value="8" />
    </include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

Notice the use of the `<group>` tags with the `ns` attribute and the `tf_prefix` param.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0